# Adding an item to a list,from the keyboard

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

Good evening,stackoverflow users,I'm here to bore you with my beginner questions again.

So I created a class,named List,which is bassicaly a linked list.

It has a function `addNode(int addData)` which bassicaly adds `addData` at the end of the list.

My question is, how can I sum these lines up:

```
cout << "list[" << count << "]=" ;
cin >> iSaidWutWut;
list.AddNode(iSaidWutWut);
```

,more specifically:

```
cin >> iSaidWutWut;
list.AddNode(iSaidWutWut);
```

,into one?

Comment: Please, be more clear. What would you like to do? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I would like to insert a new number to my list,without using an auxiliar integer.Without using iSaidWutWut, using something like `list.AddNode(cin.someMethod())`

Comment: Really bad (and useless)! The cleanest way is to use a variable to store value from standard input, then pass that value as a parameter of `AddNode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You could write a function that reads an int from `cin` and returns it, and then write

```
list.addNode(readInt());
```

But the function that does the read still needs a local variable to read into.

Comment: Ok,I just thought there is a cleaner way to do it,that's all..Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If your function were addNode(char addData), you could write:

```
list.AddNode(cin.get());
```

Comment: cin.get() yes, [see](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/) other cin methods

Answer (score 0):

Use the temporary is the cleaner version. If the optimiser think he can do better he will. Don't try to optimise every line of code you write.Do the code, if you think/want to do faster start to time your program and then try to optimise. A quick tip you should always start using a vector when you need container. Even for insertion vector is better than list in most of the cases and for storing int it is better.